# CALayer bounds don't change after setting them to a certain value

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, appkit, bounds

I am trying to display an image as the content of a CALayer slightly zoomed in by changing its bounds to a bigger size. (This is so that I can pan over it later.)
For some reason however setting the bounds does not change them or trigger an animation to do so.

This is the code I use to change the bounds:

```
self.imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
```

I have a function to compute the CGRect, but this dummy one leads to exactly the same result of the size not changing.

I have also determined, that while I can't see the size change, if I check the bounds of the layer right after setting it, it correctly has the value I set it to.

The following code is executed after setting the bounds. I couldn't find anything in it, that changes them back.

```
    self.imageLayer.add(self.generatePanAnimation(), forKey: "pan")

func generatePanAnimation() -> CAAnimation {
    var positionA = CGPoint(x: (self.bounds.width / 2), y: self.bounds.height / 2)
    var positionB = CGPoint(x: (self.bounds.width / 2), y: self.bounds.height / 2)

    positionA = self.generateZoomedPosition()
    positionB = self.generateZoomedPosition()

    let panAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    if self.direction == .AtoB {
        panAnimation.fromValue = positionA
        panAnimation.toValue = positionB
    } else {
        panAnimation.fromValue = positionB
        panAnimation.toValue = positionA
    }
    panAnimation.duration = self.panAndZoomDuration

    self.panAnimation = panAnimation
    return panAnimation
}

func generateZoomedPosition() -> CGPoint {
    let maxRight = self.zoomedImageLayerBounds.width / 2
    let maxLeft = self.bounds.width - (self.zoomedImageLayerBounds.height / 2)
    let maxUp = self.zoomedImageLayerBounds.height / 2
    let maxDown = self.bounds.height - (self.zoomedImageLayerBounds.height / 2)

    let horizontalFactor = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX)
    let verticalFactor = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX)

    let randomX = maxLeft + horizontalFactor * (maxRight - maxLeft)
    let randomY = maxDown + verticalFactor * (maxUp - maxDown)

    return CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
}
```

I even tried setting the bounds as shown below, but it didn't help.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(true, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
self.imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
CATransaction.commit()
```

I really hope someone has an idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When are you doing this?

Comment: Also: "I am trying to display an image as the content of a CALayer slightly zoomed in by changing its bounds to a bigger size." Changing the layer's bounds is not how to do this. Please explain in more detail exactly what you are _really_ trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: In the didSet-method of a variable of type NSImage. I create a fresh layer, which gets the given image as its content. I do then change the layers bounds to a not zoomed-in value (needed for other cases). And after that I add the layer as a sublayer by replacing an old one with it. Then I change the bounds as given above.
The bounds the layer visually shows however are the ones I first set it to.

Comment: I have tried not setting the bounds before. That didn't help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to change the apparent drawing size of a layer is not to change its `bounds` but to change its `transform`. To make the layer look larger, including its drawing, apply a scale transform.

Comment: Thanks a lot lot. That has solved it.
Just one little follow up question. Changing the position property is the right way to have the layer move? And what would I use the bounds for then?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You could change the `frame` instead, but don't. :)

Comment: Okay. One last one that just occurred to me: If I use the transform to change the layers drawing size, will I get issues with resolution? Like I do want the layers content to still be sharp when I zoomed in.

Comment: Where will this sharpness come from? If you are drawing the image at its actual size to start with, you have used up all your pixels already... If not, you could use CATiledLayer. — But, please, that is not your question. If you have a new question, please ask it _as a question_. This whole thing is turning out to be an x-y problem: you asked about CALayer bounds, when what you really want to know is how to zoom an image (it seems). Pounding me with extra questions after the fact like this is called "leeching".